# Command not found when running script as other user

Tags: ubuntu, root, amazon-ec2

(Using an Ubuntu EC2 on AWS)

I've a script, `/home/ubuntu/start.sh`. If I run it as `ubuntu`, it runs well. I need it to be run at launch, so I put it in `/etc/rc.local`. This will then be run as root on reboot, and this fails. I'm able to reproduce the failure by:

```
# I'm ubuntu
$ whoami
ubuntu
$ sudo su
# i'm now root
$ whoami
root
$ ./start.sh
./start.sh: line 9: npm: command not found
$ su -c ./start.sh - ubuntu
./start.sh: line 9: npm: command not found
```

So it looks like:

- root doesn't know about `npm` (installed by `ubuntu` under `/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/bin/npm` so that makes sense)
- `su -c ./start.sh - ubuntu` doesn't exactly run the script as ubuntu

How can I run this script exactly as if I was logged in as `ubuntu`?

Comment: As user ubuntu this could work to run as root: `sudo -E ./start.sh`  Regarding `/etc/rc.local`. I would run it as user ubuntu: `sudo -i  -u ubuntu /home/ubuntu/start.sh`

Answer (score 1):

`PATH=$PATH:/node/v4.2.6/bin/ ./start.sh`

Comment: I saw how that could work, but is there a more systematic way to solve this? Because I'll have to do that for each program that's unknown from root, or if I change my npm version etc. Can I not just tell root "become ubuntu for a sec, do a few things like ubuntu would do, and become root again" ?

Comment: Then launch it with ubuntu user from crontab. `@reboot`. Don't forget PATH!

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/rc.local with your favorite text editor.

`sudo nano /etc/rc.local`

And add the line `su ubuntu -c /etc/rc.local/ubuntu/start.sh &` (if that is indeed the path to your file)

This runs /etc/rc.local/ubuntu/start.sh as the user ubuntu on startup and as a background process.

Comment: Based on what you describe about starting and stopping it sounds like you'll want to make a daemon that you can /etc/init.d/myservice start (or stop)